# iOS google maps polyline disappears on zoom in

Tags: ios, google-maps, polyline

Was wondering if anyone else has this issue.  I am using the new Google Maps SDK 1.7 for iOS and have a polyline with about 49000 coordinates (basically mapping of a field) which has 49000 span colors.  When I zoom in the polyline colors disappears, looks like the polyline is still there but the colors won't show up. Is there a limit on how many span colors we can have?  This doesn't happen for polylines with about 15000 coordinates and span colors.

Comment: It appears that Google Maps api does not like more than about 16000 span colors.  Tested on SDK 1.8.1 and using a two colored dash pattern, the two colors stop rendering when about 16,000 or so are rendered. It could probably be mitigated by showing only the spans that are shown onscreen at the time of rendering, but that is something that I don't have time to implement.  Hopefully Google will fix this soon.

Comment: I added this to Google Maps API Issues and they have Acknowledged it.  Hope they fix it soon too.